# Click event on container?

Tags: go, fyne

I have a container with columns, in each column a different container. Now I want to click on a container (column item) and do something with that container.

Is it possible to create a click (tap) event on a container?

Or (which I like to avoid if possible) do I have the make a custom widget from this container?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a tap handler to any widget through extension (see https://developer.fyne.io/tutorial/extending-widgets). Your custom widget would embed an existing one and just add the `Tapped` method to enhance it. This avoids making a completely custom widget.

This is the design of Fyne - enhancement through extension instead of every widget implementing every possible combination of events.

Comment: Hi Andy, yes that I understand, but is it possible to add a Tapped method to a container?

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. No - containers are not widgets and just designed to arrange children. This is in-part becuase we believe that there should be user indication of interaction, and a container does not have such ability either. You'll need to make a trivial widget if you want to add interaction to a collection of elements.